# jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 - Dialog windows don't open on page load via AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, mobile

When loading a page from a link via AJAX in jQuery mobile, dialog windows do not fire until you refresh the page. This happens if I try to add dialogs to any other page. If I was to add **data-ajax="false"** in the link to the page that the dialog page is on, the dialog works just fine. We would like to use the jQuery mobile functionality and transitions, so the ajax false is out of the question.

All of our header info is the same on each page and all the dialogs are being called correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Mobile Demos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
</head>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="dialogpage">
    <a href="#foo2" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="c">Open Basic Dialog</a>
</div>
<div data-role="dialog" id="foo2" data-close-btn="right">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <h1>lorum ipsum header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>lorum ipsum</p>
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Ok, I get it</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can, you provide the javascript your attempting to "fire" off the dialog with?

Comment: This is jQuery Mobile, dialogs are created by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your JavaScript at the bottom of your document.

Just above the `</body>` tag. This is a best practice method for optimization on load times and other reasons. Such as in some cases with some browsers (maybe most at the time of writing this. JavaScript can typically only find whats loaded before its loaded. And in the case that your script is being loaded before the element you want to display the javascript is running its "ready" functions before the element itself is rendered. It may be firing off on a refresh due to caching. But in all failing the rest of the time as the Scripts can't find it

Comment: jQuery Mobile specifically requires scripts in the head.

Comment: Still doesn't take away from the fact that your scripts are loaded and attempting to run before the rest of your UI is rendered. I've used jQuery Mobile, and I will give you the fact that they want you to have it up top. As far as maybe the static libs and plugin files go, but if you want something to run when the dom is done loading you need to have it at the bottom of the dom so it doesn't run prematurely. Just cause jQuery Mobile says it wants to be at the top doesn't mean the rest of your scripts need to be (or should be)